# IntelliJ/Android studio hangs at startup. How to a disable a plugin that causes Intelleij/Android Studio to hang at startup?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

After installing a plugin and attempting to restart the IDE, it hangs at the startup splash screen and fails to fully initialize.   I want to disable the newly installed plugin but can't do that because the app never gets far enough along to access the plugins configuration screens.  How do a disable a plugin I suspect is causing IntelliJ oTr Android Studio to hang at startup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a file named disabled_plugins.txt that's part of the IDE configuration that allows you to disable one or more plugins.

Add the name of the plugin(s) you want to disable to this file and the IDE will not attempt to load them at startup. Note: some plugin names look a lot like Java package names and others don't.

If you're having trouble determining the package name the IDE log file will often give you a clue as to what the name of the plugin that's causing the problem is.

The location of disabled_plugins.txt on my Mac was $HOME/Library/Preferences/IntelliJIdea2018.1 for Intellij and $HOME/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio3.6 for Android Studio.

On my Windows machine it was in %HOMEPATH%.IntelliJIdea2019.3\Config and  %HOMEPATH%\AndroidStudio3.5\Config.  Your mileage may vary and you'll obviously need to adjust those paths to account for the version of the IDE you have installed if different from mine.

The log that might help you figure out which plugin is causing you problems is idea.log found in $HOME/Library/Logs/ for Mac or %HOMEPATH%.\system\log for Windows.